# How to open nokia photo images with .nrw extension?

Tags: images, photos, file-extension

I took some photos with my Nokia and they stayed with the `.nrw` extension. How can I open this format?

Comment: Perhaps we could better answer if we knew *which* Nokia. Your best option probably is to use the software that came with your phone, or to change the image format setting on your phone (if possible).

Comment: Nokia 5310 Xpress Music

Comment: People should not confuse NOKIARAW files with Nikon Raw files: both have the same `.nrw` extension, but they are not the same. The first 8 bytes of Nokia Raw files are `NOKIARAW`, and they are generated by some Nokia S40 phones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps try uploading the `.nrw` photo to the free Online Convert website (not affiliated with it in any way, shape or form):

> http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-jpg

Comment: Just tried it, the site will seemingly do a conversion of NOKIARAW files, but the output is meaningless noise, unfortunately..

Comment: worked for me. My phone is an old Nokia C2-02

Answer (score 4):

Whenever a nokia Symbian S40 series phone clicks a picture, it is initially store in an nrw file (which is like a RAW image format for these phones). Ideally, the phone's image converter runs in the background to convert these images to JPG. Your best bet would be to turn your phone off and on, so that it gets converted the next time you switch it on.

Answer (score 3):

Download this codec, which should fix it for you:

> [NRW Codec Download](http://nikonimglib.com/nrwcodec/)
>
> NRW Codec is a module that makes Nikon RAW (.NRW) image files as easy to work with as JPEG and TIFF images.

Answer (score 3):

`.NRW` is Nikon's RAW format. If you have Photoshop CS4 or later with Camera Raw 5.1, you can open and configure them natively.

Answer (score 2):

On some models you may at least change the image format your photos get saved in at `Camera > Options > Settings > Image Format`.

Comment: Most likely it is set to store pictures in RAW format. NRW is the Nikon camera RAW format

Comment: Well, as mentioned [here](http://discussions.europe.nokia.com/t5/Xseries/X2-raw-photos/m-p/769301#M4268), it is probably **not** the same file type.

Comment: The phone doesn't have that option :(

Answer (score 0):

ASHA 306

I have Asha 306 with this problem if I turn off the phone BEFORE camera software elaborate .nrw file (the original format used by S40 system) in .jpg file.

.nrw file is NOKIARAW file and there isn't software able to elaborate it.

I found how resolve this issue.

We have to COPY the .nrw file in another folder on the phone's memory card using "FILE" app (Eg on memory card's root folder).
In few seconds S40 software elaborates files in .jpg format.

Now we can Copy the .jpg file in its original position